# IndexError: too many indices for array when trying to plot a spectrogram of a .wav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, wav, spectrogram

I am trying to plot a spectrogram of a .wav file. 
The strange thing about the way the below code behaves is that it works on some .wav files and fails on others. I suspect that this is because some .wav files have a different number of channels compared to others. However I have no idea how to determine how many channels a .wav file contains. I've looked at this stack overflow post prior to posting my question: [What is a channel in a .wav file format?Do all channels play simultaneaously when a wav file is played?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995936/what-is-a-channel-in-a-wav-file-formatdo-all-channels-play-simultaneaously-whe)

I've pasted one of my methods below which tries to convert a a filepath(myAudio) into a jpg with filepath(fileNameToSaveTo).

```
def individualWavToSpectrogram(myAudio, fileNameToSaveTo):
print(myAudio)
#Read file and get sampling freq [ usually 44100 Hz ]  and sound object
samplingFreq, mySound = wavfile.read(myAudio)

#Check if wave file is 16bit or 32 bit. 24bit is not supported
mySoundDataType = mySound.dtype

#We can convert our sound array to floating point values ranging from -1 to 1 as follows

mySound = mySound / (2.**15)

#Check sample points and sound channel for duel channel(5060, 2) or  (5060, ) for mono channel

mySoundShape = mySound.shape
samplePoints = float(mySound.shape[0])

#Get duration of sound file
signalDuration =  mySound.shape[0] / samplingFreq

#If two channels, then select only one channel
mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]

#Plotting the tone

# We can represent sound by plotting the pressure values against time axis.
#Create an array of sample point in one dimension
timeArray = numpy.arange(0, samplePoints, 1)

#
timeArray = timeArray / samplingFreq

#Scale to milliSeconds
timeArray = timeArray * 1000

#Plot the tone
plt.plot(timeArray, mySoundOneChannel, color='Black')
#plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')
#plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
print("trying to save")
plt.savefig('/Users/billybobjoe/Desktop/SavedSpecs' + fileNameToSaveTo + '.jpg')
print("saved")
plt.show()
```

This produces the following error on some of my .wav files
 line 57, in individualWavToSpectrogram
    mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array

The line of code that fails is

```
mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
```

How do I check the number of channels that a .wav file has, and how do I set mySoundOneChannel accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the data array `mySound` will have shape `(nSamples, nChannels)` if there are multiple channels. If there is one channel, `mySound` will have shape `(nSamples,)`.

Here, your audio file must have only one channel, and therefore you cannot index it as if it is a 2D array.

Hence, you should be able to replace

```
mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
```

with something like

```
if len(mySound.shape) > 1:
    mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
else:
    mySoundOneChannel = mySound
```

To get the number of channels, you should be able to do:

```
if len(mySound.shape) > 1:
    nChannels = mySound.shape[1]
else:
    nChannels = 1
```